# .htaccess configuration for Slim PHP REST API on a subdomain?

Tags: php, api, .htaccess, slim

I currently have an api.php file built using the [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/). I'd like to use something like api.mydomain.com (or mydomain.com/api) to reference the API file and make calls using http://api.mydomain.com as the base url. The Slim documentation calls for the following to be added to your .htacess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

But if I'm correct, that returns the index.php file if the file requested doesn't exist. How best to setup a rewrite from api.mydomain.com or mydomain.com/api to the index.php? Everything we've found points to configuring this using .htaccess.

We used the following rewrite rule, but this resulted in having slashes ('/') appended to all of our URLs, which also required us to reconfigure our routes in Slim as well. (Example: "/messages" became "/messages/" and "/threads?id=123" became "/threads/?id=123")

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ api.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to fix this with some complex apache rules (see the links included), this was actually addresses in Slim version 2.2+ so you are far better off just updating your version of slim (phar version set to "2.*" or "2.2.*").

http://www.slimframework.com/install

If you decide to go the apache route (not recommended) then check these links:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23382/how-to-remove-trailing-slashes-from-url-with-htaccess

[htaccess remove .php, .html and trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481137/htaccess-remove-php-html-and-trailing-slash)