# htaccess remove .php, .html and trailing slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am trying to remove .php .html and traling slash from url using htaccess,how ever this code working fine for php but not for html and trailing slash

For PHP

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

For HTML

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/$ /$1 is working for me for trailing slash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
# externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file and remove index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.(?:html?|php)/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# internally add php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# internally add html extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply,here the index.html url not working for me when i enter url like http://www.mywdesign.com/index.html/web-dev-ecommerce-services it shows page not found,also when i use url like  http://www.mywdesign.com/index.php/web-dev-ecommerce-services in browser it goes to   http://www.mywdesign.com//web-dev-ecommerce-services, so double slashes comes. can you please help?

Comment: See the update it will fix `//` problem. However for `/index.html/web-dev-ecommerce-services` as per requirements it will redirect to `/web-dev-ecommerce-services` is this not happening? OR do you want to leave it as `/index.html/web-dev-ecommerce-services` itself?

Comment: hi thanks,index.php and trailing slash is working fine now,but index.html not going its not redirecting to /web-dev-ecommece-service however same thing isworking fine with php but in index.html case its not working

Comment: That's why I think it is not good idea to strip `index.html` from `/index.html/web-dev-ecommerce-services` btw this is really a strange URL. I have seen similar scheme with `index.php` but not with `index.html`

Comment: the seo guy says when we write in index.html between url it should strip automatically.this is something happens in many websites but here when i write index.php strips using your code but index.html not

Comment: With the latest update it should be stripping off `index.html` also.

Comment: This seems to fail to remove the .php extension when I enter a trailing slash.  i.e. contact.php/ becomes contact.php.  It removes the .php section when I don't have a trailing slash.  Is there anything else needed to make these work?