# Removing file extions(.html & .php) And Trailing Slash in Website URL

Tags: php, html

I am planning to have **one code** that will be able remove file extensions **.html, .php** and **trailing slash** at the same time on the website URL. How can I do?.

For example;

```
https://www.example.com/about/         to       https://www.example.com/about

https://www.example.com/about.html     to       https://www.example.com/about

https://www.example.com/about.php      to       https://www.example.com/about
```

==============================================================

**FROM THE QUESTION I ASKED ABOVE **2 DAYS** AGO THIS IS WHAT I DID AND IT'S WORKING FINE WITH *Web Server Apache***

However if you think there is something to add and make it so beautiful, it will be better.

**.htaccess** file

```html
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On



#=========== For HTML =====================



# If it's a request to index(.html) 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+/)?index(\.html)?(\?.*)?\  [NC]
# Remove it. 
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index(\.html)?$ /%1 [R=301,L]



# if request has a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/$
# but it isn't a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 !-d
# and if the trailing slash is removed and a .html appended to the end, it IS a file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.html -f
# redirect without trailing slash
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]




RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# And a HTML file exists.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -f
# And there is a trailing slash redirect to remove it. 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L] 



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# And a HTML file exists.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -f
# And there is no trailing slash show the index.html. 
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.html [L]   


# Remove HTML extensions. 
# If it's a request from a browser, not an internal request by Apache/mod_rewrite. 
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
# And the request has a HTML extension. Redirect to remove it. 
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]


# If the request exists with a .html extension. 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
# And there is no trailing slash, rewrite to add the .html extension. 
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]






#=========== For PHP =====================






# if request has a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/$
# but it isn't a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 !-d
# and if the trailing slash is removed and a .php appended to the end, it IS a file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
# redirect without trailing slash
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]



# Add missing trailing slashes to directories if a matching .php does not exist. 
# If it's a request to a directory. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ -d
# And a PHP file does not (!) exist.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
# And there is not trailing slash redirect to add it. 
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]




RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# And a PHP file exists.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
# And there is a trailing slash redirect to remove it. 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L] 



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# And a PHP file exists.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
# And there is no trailing slash show the index.php. 
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Well, you need to implement a rewriting rule for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [htaccess remove .php, .html and trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481137/htaccess-remove-php-html-and-trailing-slash)

Comment: You can achieve this by creating a `.htaccess` file with the respective rules linked in the question I have linked above.

Comment: Yep, but only if OP is using Apache

Comment: Depends on what webserver you're using

Comment: How should I implement the rewriting rule, @arkascha.

Comment: You need to check how to implement it for the http server you are using (you did not tell us, so we cannot say). All servers offer such thing. Then I suggest you take a look at that server's documentation and maybe work through a tutorial or two.

Comment: Let me try it @Skully

Comment: So what http server is that provider using? And what are you using in your local development setup?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I am not grumpy or teasing you. Not at all. I am trying to tell you that this is your setup. And you should know your setup. Because you have to implement what you want to achieve. We are not a free coding service here, we are here to _help_ you, but that means you have to do your own work. For that you need to now your setup and how that works. Which apparently we did not bother to find out so far...

Comment: Hostigator uses Apache  @arkascha

Comment: No, I cann't get you wrong my friend @arkascha someone who takes his time to listen and help. I know tha t I am here to learn fro you. And that is why  I have asked knowing that there are people like you to help me. So feel free

Comment: On both  my local development set up and provider I am using  Apache HTTP server @arkascha.

Comment: OK, in that case you should implement rewriting rules in a "distributed configuration file" (typically named ".htaccess"), so that you can use the same setup in your local development setup and at your provider. You need to enable the interpretation of such files in your local setup, read about the `AllowOverride` directive for that (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride). Your configuration file should reside in the top folder which acts as your http server's `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. Then take a look at the answer anubhava gave in the link posted by Skully above.

Comment: Once you implemented that you need to test locally. Monitor your http server's error log file. The documentation of apache's rewriting module should be your first stop to get help: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html If you run into issues with your own implementation which you don't understand or cannot resolve, _then_ is the time to post your implementation here, describe what you see instead of what you would expect. That is where we can help.

Comment: Wow!, this is resourceful material I ever wanted @arkascha, I can find it so helpful. I was just still trying  Skully's  solution he provideded above, I hope with all these I should get through. I will let you know.

Comment: Thank you @arkascha I have succeeded. Now it works. Your contribution and Skully's have helped.

Comment: Thank you @Skully for your help. I am now through.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved, it's good practice to post the answer of how you resolved it in case anyone else stumbles upon this in the future.