# How can I check for an invalid directory and return a 404?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to place a .htaccess file in an httpdocs directory which I hope to use across a number of sites with a similar structure and end up with clean URLs for a number of scenarios.

I found a great recent post ([Removing file extions(.html & .php) And Trailing Slash in Website URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612044/removing-file-extions-html-php-and-trailing-slash-in-website-url)) which gave me almost exactly what I was after but my experience with rewrites is very limited and I'm really struggling to find the last piece of the puzzle.

I have a number of conditions to pass for this to work completely;

**pages with html extensions:**

`example.com/valid_page.html` presents `example.com/valid_page` [pass]

**pages without html extensions:**

`example.com/valid_page` presents `example.com/valid_page.html` [pass]

`example.com/valid_page/` removes slash and presents `example.com/valid_page.html` [pass]

**directories with same name as pages:**

`example.com/valid_page_same_as_dir/valid_page` presents `example.com/valid_dir_same_as_page/valid_page.html` [pass]

`example.com/valid_page_same_as_dir` presents `example.com/valid_page_same_as_dir.html` [pass]

**non-existent pages and directories:**

`example.com/something_invalid` presents 404 error doc at explicit url [pass]

`example.com/valid_dir/something_invalid` presents 404 error doc at explicit url [pass]

`example.com/valid_page/something_invalid` presents 404 error doc at explicit url [fail - actually presents 500 internal server error]

As you can see, this last one is the issue. Where a page name exists and a directory with the same does not exist, then we experience an internal server error instead of throwing a 404.

I've tried tweaking this so much with the resources I've been able to find to get this to work but I just cannot get this last condition to be met. The contents of the .htaccess file as it currently stands is below.

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

# If it's a request to index(.html) 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+/)?index(\.html)?(\?.*)?\  [NC]
# Remove it. 
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index(\.html)?$ /%1 [R=301,L]

# if request has a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/$
# but it isn't a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 !-d
# and if the trailing slash is removed and a .html appended to the end, it IS a file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.html -f
# redirect without trailing slash
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# And a HTML file exists.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -f
# And there is a trailing slash redirect to remove it. 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# And a HTML file exists.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -f
# And there is no trailing slash show the index.html. 
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.html [L]   

# Remove HTML extensions. 
# If it's a request from a browser, not an internal request by Apache/mod_rewrite. 
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
# And the request has a HTML extension. Redirect to remove it. 
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# If the request exists with a .html extension. 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
# And there is no trailing slash, rewrite to add the .html extension. 
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/404
```

If anybody has any ideas about how we can overcome this I'd really appreciate your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: Try changing your last rule `RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]
` to `RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ $1.html [QSA,L]` .

Comment: FYI, specifying an absolute URL for your 404 ErrorDocument, is still fundamentally wrong. That will cause a _redirect_ to that URL, meaning any bots will not get the proper 404 status code for the URL they originally requested any more.

Comment: @AmitVerma thank you, I really appreciate this - this does get me a little closer to what I was after. This overcomes the issue that was failing before, but presents something new; if I navigate to example.com/valid_page_same_as_dir it works still until I place a slash at the end. So example.com/valid_page_same_as_dir/ actually now presents a 403 error on the server. I assume this has to be caught somehow, and from looking through the logic I can sort of understand that this isn't intended to be caught at the moment is it? Do you have any advice for this item please? Thanks

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the input. I do agree, and it's somewhat of a sticking plaster until I get round to that item. I do have a solution in mind for this and will be one of the next things in the list but wanted something there for now to catch all very simplistically.